# Cómo se accede a variable de sesión desde jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

Desde jquery, a través de Ajax, seteo una variable de sesión en un PHP.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['nombre']=$usuario;
```

Luego, necesito imprimir en el jquery el valor de esa variable:

```
$(document).on('change', '.cmb_articulo', function () 
{
alert($_SESSION['nombre']);
```

pero esto último no funciona.

Por favor, agradeceré la ayuda. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Es una variante de la primera pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mostrar la salida de PHP debe codificar la salida mediante la función [json-encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)

```
$(document).on('change', '.cmb_articulo', function () {
       var variable = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['nombre']); ?>;
       alert(variable);
  });
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda; lo incorporé y funcionó perfectamente. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que veo es que no estas iniciando los tags para trabajar con php, quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```html
$(document).on('change', '.cmb_articulo', function () 
{
alert(<?php echo $_SESSION['nombre']; ?>);
```

Comment: Faltarían comillas. Si `$_SESSION['nombre']` es un alfanumérico esta solución fallará porque lanzará un error diciendo que la variable no se encuentra.

Comment: Te comento que probé tu sugerencia y tal cual, no funciona, pero añadiéndole lo que indica @Dev. Joel más arriba, funciona perfectamente. Te agradezco tu tiempo y ayuda.